# Formula (fx) field character color

Tags: google-sheets

I cannot read the orange characters in the formula field in Google Sheets. How do I set character color in the formula (*fx*) field of Google Sheets?

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is not possible. In the Google Sheets web app, the rich text formatting is supported only when editing data in cells. Ref. [Edit & format a spreadsheet](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/46973?hl=en).